# UITextField - Stacked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

How do I create "stacked" UITextFields like the picture attached?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a UITableView with the style set to "Grouped"

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITextField *myTxtField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
  [TxtUserID setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:15]];
  [TxtUserID setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 20, 10)];
  [TxtUserID setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
  [cell addSubview:myTxtField];
  cell.accessoryView = myTxtField;
}

Hope this will help you out
```